# Spring MVC annotation based configuration not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I tried to create a simple Spring MVC project with help of [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/)
but when I deployed it is showing 404 server error.Since I am a beginner to spring MVC I couldn't make out what is wrong in project inspite of going through all the answers here and other places as well.I would greatly appreciate your help in figuring out.

These are the Contents:

- **POM.xml**

  ```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com</groupId>
      <artifactId>deevigeweb</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>deevigeweb Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.1</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
              <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
              <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.0</version>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
              <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
              <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
             <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

     </dependencies>
     <build>
        <finalName>deevigeweb</finalName>
     </build>
  </project>
  ```
- **Servlet Initializer**(DeevigeServletInitializer.java)

  ```
  package com.deevigeweb.config;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

  public class DeevigeServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

      @Override
      protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
         return new Class[] {DeevigeWebMVCConfig.class};
      }

      @Override
      protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
         return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected String[] getServletMappings() {
         return new String[] {"/"};
      }

  }
  ```
- **Web MVC Config**(DeevigeWebMVCConfig.java)

  ```
  package com.deevigeweb.config;

  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

  @EnableWebMvc
  @Configuration
  @ComponentScan({"com.deevigeweb"})
  public class DeevigeWebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
      @Override
      public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
           registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
  }

  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
      InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views");
      resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return resolver;
  }

  }
  ```
- **Controller**(SearchViewController.java)

  ```
  package com.deevigeweb.controllers.webapp;

  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

  public class SearchViewController {
      @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView doLanding(){
          return new ModelAndView("searchview");
      }
  }
  ```
- **JSP**(searchview.jsp)

  ```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html >
  <html>
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
          <title>Welcome</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```
- **Directory Structure**
  [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO6v1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe adding the trailing slash does the trick for you:

```
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
```

Also add a `@Controller` annotation on your `SearchViewController` class

Answer (score 1):

Add a class level  `@Controller` annotation on `SearchViewController`. You missed it.

```
@Controller
public class SearchViewController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doLanding(){
        return new ModelAndView("searchview");
    }
}
```

Now the URL [localhost:8080/deevigeweb/](http://localhost:8080/deevigeweb/) will return `searchview.jsp` page.

And `web.xml` is not required in your project as this is pure Java based configuration.

Comment: one more thing i missed was trailing slash after views.Thanks